# Hot key to focus and raise a window (under cursor) in Win 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is this only me?  Sometimes I want to focus and raise a window W that is currently mostly underneath another window.  The remaining exposed part of W are mostly some active buttons or links.  I only want to raise the window W, not activating any of those buttons/links.  I often spend a lot of time to find an area that is NOT an active button/link to click on, simply for the intention the raise and focus on the window.

I wish there is a window hotkey that does that -- that is, the hot key would signal to Windows that the user wants to focus and raise the window that is currently *under the cursor*

I have read through this page but could not find the answer there:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I've never had a problem with this. Besides, you can click e.g. on a window border, and there are other ways to toggle windows - task bar, alt-tab menu.
But if you really after this - you can use an Autohotkey script, still you'll need 
to occupy some key since it must be a system-wide hotkey.

Example script bound to Capslock:

```
SendMode Input 
SetStoreCapsLockMode, Off

Capslock::
    MouseGetPos , , , window_id
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %window_id%
    WinActivate, %title%
    ; tooltip %title%
return
```